# Delete a particular language version of a page in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore

I created a page in Sitecore in the English language. I published and the page was available in the web database. I now added a french version of the page and published. Again, the page was available in the web database.
Now, I deleted the french version and published. However, the french version continues to stay in the web database (it's gone from the master database as I deleted it). I do check the relevant languages and sub items when I publish.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Which version/update of Sitecore are you using? You could try a republish and/ore publish the parent item (with subitems checked)

Comment: 8.2. I am checking subitems when I publish.

Comment: Which update version/revision of 8.2 ?

Comment: Sitecore version Sitecore.NET 8.2 (rev. 170407)

Comment: Assuming you also tried the `Republish`, it could be related to [Publishing Issues in 8.2 u3](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/136794), there are a number of known issues in that particular version of Sitecore.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the french version unpublishable if all else fails, and publish that which should hide it. But I think the real issue is that you didn't properly publish the item when you deleted it. You can also switch to the web db in CE, and navigate to the french version and delete it there.